# onChange return undefined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import JSONEditor from "jsoneditor";
import "jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.css";

const JSONReact = ({ json, mode, onChange }) => {
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const props = {
      onChangeText: (value) => {
        console.log(value, "vv");
        onChange(value);
      },
      modes: ["code"]
    };
    ref1.current = new JSONEditor(ref2.current, props);

    if (json) {
      ref1.current.set(json);
    }

    return () => {
      ref1.current.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (json) {
      ref1?.current.update(json);
    }
  }, [json]);

  return <div ref={ref2} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('{"cars": "22w-08w-23"}');
  const onChange = (j) => {
    console.log(j);
    setState(j);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <JSONReact mode="code" onChange={onChange} json={JSON.parse(state)} />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When i type something inside editor i get undefined in `console.log(j);`, but i don't understand why. Who can help to fix it?

 https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-khorana-pdem1l?file=/src/App.js:909-929

Answer (score 2):

Well it is expected as in the docs it clearly says "This callback does not pass the changed contents", over here [https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md#:~:text=This%20callback%20does%20not%20pass%20the%20changed%20contents](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md#:%7E:text=This%20callback%20does%20not%20pass%20the%20changed%20contents)

However, There are two ways to do it, that I found from here

https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md#configuration-options

**First Way:** use getText() from JSONEditor object to get the current value, since it will return you string so just parse it in json and pass inside your callback (onChange) prop.

#### JavaScript

```
const props = {
  onChange: () => {
    onChange(JSON.parse(ref1.current.getText()));
  },
  modes: ["code"]
};
ref1.current = new JSONEditor(ref2.current, props);
```

**Second way:** just use onChangeText and it will give the string in the callback,

```
const props = {
  onChangeText: (value) => {
    onChange(JSON.parse(value));
  },
  modes: ["code"]
};
ref1.current = new JSONEditor(ref2.current, props);
```

EDIT 1: added JSON validation check before calling onChange Props

```
  const isValidJSON = (jsonString) => {
    try {
      JSON.parse(jsonString);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const props = {
      onChangeText: (value) => {
        isValidJSON(value) && onChange(JSON.parse(value));
      },
      modes: ["code"]
    };
    ref1.current = new JSONEditor(ref2.current, props);
```

EDIT 2: adding error validation using `validate()`, here in this case we can remove `isValidJSON(value)` check from below code since we are already checking for JSON errors using `validate()`.

```
onChangeText: (value) => {
        const errors = ref1.current.validate();
        errors.then((err) => {
          if (!err.length) {
            isValidJSON(value) && onChange(JSON.parse(value));
          } else {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: i changed the the code accordinf to your comments, plus i added a new initial value. When i type in editor, outside the text, i get the error: `JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 2 column 23 of the JSON data`. But i need when i will type a invalid json to dysplay the editor not to brake it with this error. Could you help please?

Comment: could you help please?

Comment: you can always validate the JSON string before actually putting them into JSON.parse and calling onChnage, added a code snippet that might help you

Comment: why `onChangeJSON` does not work but only `onChangeText`?

Comment: `onChangeJSON` not available for the `modes: ["code"]` , as of documentation `Only applicable when option mode is tree, form, or view`  https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md#:~:text=changed%20JSON%20document.-,Only%20applicable%20when,-option%20mode%20is

Comment: i changed the the code to get the error state. Inside onChange function the error is not updated. Could you help please? Thanks a lot. Here i should get the updated error  console.log(valid);

Comment: could you help please?

Comment: You should try `validate()` method available on  `JSONEditor` object which is ref1.current in your case so you can do something like this `ref1.current.validate()`, it returns a promise with array of errors, if array is empty that means JSON is fine.  Adding an example in above answer you can have a look

Comment: is there possible to test onChange function in  using cypress? I want to test ex: i type and to detect if the onChange function was called. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a normal behaviour of JSONEditor, according to docs:

> {function} onChange()
>
> Set a callback function triggered when the contents of the JSONEditor
> change. This callback does not pass the changed contents, use get() or
> getText() for that. Note that get() can throw an exception in mode
> text, code, or preview, when the editor contains invalid JSON. Will
> only be triggered on changes made by the user, not in case of
> programmatic changes via the functions set, setText, update, or
> updateText. See also callback functions onChangeJSON(json) and
> onChangeText(jsonString). `